# Why is the Hint property not available when selecting multiple components?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-11-alexandria

Generally, if you select two components in the IDE designer, the object inspector shows all properties that they have in common.

I wanted to clear the `Hint` property of several DevExpress `TcxLabel` components, and noticed that the object inspector does not show the `Hint` property. The same happens with e.g. two `TLabel` components.

Is this a bug, or is there a logical/technical reason that the `Hint` property does not behave as expected? The other string property `Caption` shows fine with multi-select.

Comment: The typical reason for this happening is that you've included at least one control that does not have a Hint property, which means that the property isn't shared by all selected controls and therefore isn't shown. Are you sure you've not accidentally done that by mistake?

Comment: @KenWhite. Nope. As commented to Uwe: "even a brand new VCL application does not show the hint property on TLabel multiselect". That app had only two TLabels and I did not select the form.

Answer (score 3):

Some properties are not eligible for participation in a multiple selection. The comment in *DesignIntf.pas* for paMultiSelect gives a hint:

> Some properties are not appropriate for multi-selection (e.g. the Name
> property).

Out of my head *ImageIndex* is in this list, but *Hint* usually is not. A quick check here confirms that *Hint* is still in the Object Inspector when two *TLabel* are selected. It may be some expert or design package causing it for you.

Comment: Mmm, interesting, even a brand new VCL application does not show the hint property on TLabel multiselect... Well, I'm not going to trace all installed design packages...

Comment: I can multi-select any combination of labels (regular, DevExpress or Raize) on a new form and the hint property is settable.  Delphi 11.3 patch 1 and Developer Express v23.1.6. Clicking the ellipsis in the hint property even brings up a formatted hint editor. Not sure what is providing that.